# How to pass props to DatePicker in NextJS functional Component

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, next.js

In nextJS project, I have a component that works with DatePicker. I need to pass showMonthYearDropdown or showMonthDropdown showYearDropdown as props to that copmonent. This is DatePickerComponent component

```
 const DatePickerComponent: React.FC<{ name: string; text?: (text: string) => string }> = ({
  name,
  text,
  ...props
}) =>
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <>
      <DatePicker
        dateFormat="dd/mm/yyyy"
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
        {...props}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

And this is how I use this component with props

```
<DatePickerComponent name='datepicker' showMonthDropdown showYearDropdown />
```

or

```
<DatePickerComponent name='datepicker' showMonthYearDropdown />
```

But I get this error: `Property 'showMonthDropdown' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes`.

Does anybody know what is wrong with this code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What library are you using for `datepicker`?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You will need to declare those types to the component itself:**

```
const DatePickerComponent: React.FC<{
  name: string;
  text?: (text: string) => string;
  showMonthDropdown: boolean;
  showYearDropdown: boolean;
  showMonthYearDropdown: boolean;
}>;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But why we just can't use ...props without specifying each one by one?

Comment: No, we can't, It's the nature of React with typescript. You will have to declare types that you want to have in the props, otherwise, we could lose type tracking.

Answer (score 0):

some of them are optional

```
const DatePickerComponent: React.FC<{
  name: string;
  text?: (text: string) => string;
  showMonthDropdown?: boolean;
  showYearDropdown?: boolean;
  showMonthYearDropdown?: boolean;
}>;
```